# LyX: Import LaTeX from Clipboard

Tags: lyx

Whenever I try:

**File -> Import -> LaTeX (clipboard)...**

I'm presented with a dialog for selecting a latex file to import. Should it not import what I currently have on my clipboard? Or am I misinterpreting what this is supposed to do?

I'm running Lyx 2.3.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS through the Gnome 3 Desktop Environment. Do I need to change the Lyx settings to give it access to the clipboard? Copy and paste inside a Lyx document works as expected.

Obviously, this isn't a major issue. I can always use ERT (Crtl+l) or I can copy and paste LaTeX code into a file, save it and then import as normal via:

**File -> Import -> LaTeX (plain)...**

But it would be convenient to be able to create a new Lyx file by importing LaTeX code from the clipboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new LyX file by importing LaTeX code from the clipboard, go to File > New and then Edit > Paste Special > Paste from LaTeX. If you want to make a short-cut that does both of those actions with one shortcut, let me know and I'll add that to this answer.

I think you're right that the File > Import > LaTeX (clipboard) is not working correctly. Please file a bug report at https://www.lyx.org/trac.

Comment: Thanks, that works. And I just created a bug report: [https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/11657](https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/11657)